# Fencing Sport practise circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I would like to build a (my guess is a pretty simple) circuit to help training with the foil weapon in 'Olympic Fencing'.

The electronic foil blade has a two wire socket to connect the electric scoring system.  ([circuit description](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fencing/Electrical_Equipment_Repair#Foil) ).  At rest (ex. the beginning of each point) there is a closed circuit on the foil blade and surprisingly the circuit is opened to indicate an off target hit.  There is a separate circuit that involves the opponent's metallic jacket that is used to score 'on target' hits.

I would like to use the circuit on the blade to make a buzzer sound when the circuit is opened for a hit. The circuit would let the fencer know that his tip has touched something like a training target and the button was depressed.

I've come across this diagram on a [image][All About Circuits](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/simple-circuit-to-detect-open-gate.128690/) about how to use LEDs to signal that a garden gate (circuit) is open.

Since I'm a noob it's not clear whether the same type of circuit can be used with a buzzer, say in parallel to the green diode?  The buzzer would change the resistance of that branch of the circuit.

**Any advice on how to wire the fencing training buzzer would be greatly appreciated.  Along with advice whether to use a breadboard or leverage a microbit hobby processor to help?
What are the options ?**

Comment: The disadvantage of this circuit is that the red LED will blink only very briefly when contact is made, so if contact is short enough, you won't see it. If you search for "wire loop game circuit" you come across circuits like this: https://online.mhjc.school.nz/mod/resource/view.php?id=90961 which have a short "memory" so that even if the contact was short, you can still detect it.

Comment: Using the microbit sounds like a great idea; look at examples for reading a button, and change them such that a brief open (eg a pullup resistor acting when the circuit no longer shunts to ground) causes a half second or so train of pulses on a pin connected to a piezo element.  During that output, the code should *ignore* the input circuit.  After that it can go back to looking at it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie So the capacitor 'discharges' powering a light or buzzer for a longer interval?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ok, thanks can look into that circuit too.